# Why is Magento 2 Klarna Client Error resulting in 401 unauthorized response? Updating API credentials didn't work

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2, klarna

This is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acv9z.png)

`"client error" 'POST https://api.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized`response:
{"http_status_code":401,"http_status_message":"Unauthorized","internal_message":"authorization_error"}. Please check credentials and API version selected.`

I have updated to new api credentials and gone through the api integration in magento backend,
I have re-indexed the site through the terminal,
I have cleared the cache through Magento,
I have cleared the cache on cloudflare too,

I spoke to Klarna support and they said

> Klarna Checkout is a legacy product that is only used on a playground account for testing purposes (as it replaces the checkout rather than adds Klarna as an option).

and gave me Klarna integration guides and said I'd need to find out my magento version

Magento 2.4.4 and above:
klarna.com/platform-solutions/adobe-commerce/adobe-commerce-244-and-above/installation/

Magento up to 2.4.3
klarna.com/platform-solutions/adobe-commerce/adobe-commerce-23x-243/kp-overview/

When I looked at Magento Version it said:

[magento version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njIgz.png)

To which the support person had no idea how to rectify. I since used
magereport and that told me

CE 2.4.2-p1 - 2.4.2-p2

So I tried following the guides to upgrade klarna and that didn't work because

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9qzq.png)

In the meantime I have disabled Klarna because you couldn't actually pay with it in the end. So I'm going to have to reinstall or try again or something and I'm pulling my hair out because no one at work can help me and the client is requesting changes to the website, which I cannot achieve.